.net core CORS response headers missing
I'm trying to get 'set-cookie' header that comes back from my server after login request.
I set everything on server side to allow and expose all:
program.cs cors
I get all i need in network section in chrome tools:
Set-Cookie is here as it should
I console log out headers of response and get all but missing the one i need:
All but set-cookie missing
Probably checked most of the cors configurations with (with SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true) as well) and still didn't manage to get this set-cookie on client side.

Welcome, but lease do not upload images of code/data/errors and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Be aware that Set-Cookie is a so-called forbidden response-header name; as such, browsers never expose it to clients, regardless of whether or how the requested resource is configured for CORS.

Does this answer your question? Access-Control-Expose-Headers does not work to allow JS client side to read cookies

if someone strugle with this problem, add 'withCredentials: true' into your request, after that 'set-cookie' should be automaticly set after response

Some example code would make this answer a lot clearer :)

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
